# Django if identify form class div

Tags: jquery, ajax, class, django-forms

Simple quetion.
I call form ajax.

```
<body>
<div id="head"><a class="button">CLICK</a></head> - maybe head place
<div id="content"><a class="button">CLICK</a></head> - in content, other place

<form style="opacity:0;" metod="POST">
<input type="text" name="phone">
<input type="{% if id="content" %}text{% else %}hidden{% endif %}" name="phone">
</form>
</body>
```

my problem:  {% if id="content" %}  - how realize

Comment: What's the instance of your Form or ModelForm called? You cold just use Javascript for this

Answer (score 0):

Identifying a form in template isn't possible by default.

According to `dir(MyForm())` you have only these options:

```
'files': '{}',
'is_bound': 'False',
'error_class': '<class 'django.forms.util.ErrorList'>',
'empty_permitted': 'False',
'fields': '{}',
'initial': '{}',
'label_suffix': ':',
'prefix': 'None',
'_changed_data': 'None',
'data': '{}',
'_errors': 'None',
'auto_id': 'id_%s',
```

You can ascertain a form's class name by this line, though this is 'private' (you can tell by the underscores) and (unfortunately) not accessible by the form in the template:

```
MyForm.__class__.__name__
```

So you've got a few options to identify your form in your template. Many ways to skin that cat. I'll only present one really cheap solution I used recently:

forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_form_name = "one" #add attr to form class
    ...
```

template

```
{{form.my_form_name}}
```

Not super clever but very robust.

---

So obviously then for your use case you could say:

```
<a class="two"><input type="{% if form.my_form_name = "one" %}text{% else %}hidden{% endif %}"></a>
```